# Error: [ng:areq] Angular chart js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

estoy realizando unos gráficos con la librería Angular chart js, he probado con los ejemplos que encontré en la página y funciona correctamente pero al intentar realizar dos gráficos en la misma página consigo el siguiente erro

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=BarCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

He aquí mi codigo 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Barra</title>
 <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body">
 <div ng-app="app">
  <div id="container" class="container">
   <div class="row" ng-controller="BarCtrl">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Barra</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <canvas id="base" class="chart chart-bar"
          chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series">
        </canvas> 
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div ng-app="app1">
 <div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="BarCtrl">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Barra1</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <canvas id="base" class="chart chart-bar"
          chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series">
        </canvas> 
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="barra.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

y este es el Js:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope) { $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012']; $scope.series = ['Series A']; $scope.data = [
[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]]; });

angular.module("app1", ["chart.js"]).controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope {$scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012']; $scope.series = ['Series A']; $scope.data = [
[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]]; });
```

Son datos solamente de prueba por eso son los mismos, que creen que puede fallar para que me esté saliendo este error ?

Comment: Usar varios `ng-app` en tu aplicación no es correcto ya que sólo el primero surtirá efecto, también estas incluyendo la librería `angular-chart` dos veces, una minificada y otra sin minificar. El código javascript que incluyes está declarado en `barra.js` o es otro fichero?

Answer (score 1):

Este es tu error:

> Error: ng:areq Bad Argument
>
> Argument 'BarCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

**¿Qué está ocurriendo?**

La directiva ng-controller está llamando a "BarCtrl" un controlador que todavía no existe.

Te falla porque "barra.js" lo incluyes más tarde con tu:

```
<script src="barra.js"></script>
```

Deberías declararlo al principio de tu HTML antes de que se produzca la llamada con **ng-controller.**

Por otro lado lo que te comenta **devconcept** es totalmente cierto. Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a la guia de estilo de ToddMoto (está en castellano):

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/i18n/es-ES.md